# how to highlight text as per audio on a website in realtime as the audio narrates it

Tags: reactjs, annotations, text-to-speech

I am trying to figure out which technology to use to hightlight a text as per the audio. Much like what `https://speechify.com/` is doing.
[image]

This is assuming I am able to run a TTS algo and I am able to convert text to speech.
I have tried multiple sources but I am unable to pinpoint the exact technology or methodology of highlighting the text as the audio speaks.

Any help would be much appreciated. I have already wasted 2 days on the internet to figure this out but no luck :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple approach would be to use the event listener provided by the [SpeechSynthesisUtterance boundary event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/boundary_event) to highlight words with vanilla JS. The emitted event gives us char indices, so no need to go crazy with regexes or super AI stuff :)

Before anything else, make sure the API is available

```
const synth = window.speechSynthesis
if (!synth) {
  console.error('no tts for you!')
  return
}
```

The tts utterance emits an 'boundary' event, we can use it to highlight text.

```
let text = document.getElementById('text')
let originalText = text.innerText
let utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(originalText)
utterance.addEventListener('boundary', event => {
  const { charIndex, charLength } = event
  text.innerHTML = highlight(originalText, charIndex, charIndex + charLength)
})
synth.speak(utterance)
```

Full example:

```
const btn = document.getElementById("btn")

const highlight = (text, from, to) => {
  let replacement = highlightBackground(text.slice(from, to))
  return text.substring(0, from) + replacement + text.substring(to)
}
const highlightBackground = sample => `<span style="background-color:yellow;">${sample}</span>`

btn && btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const synth = window.speechSynthesis
  if (!synth) {
    console.error('no tts')
    return
  }
  let text = document.getElementById('text')
  let originalText = text.innerText
  let utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(originalText)
  utterance.addEventListener('boundary', event => {
    const { charIndex, charLength } = event
    text.innerHTML = highlight(originalText, charIndex, charIndex + charLength)
   })
  synth.speak(utterance)
})
```

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/tts-with-word-highlight-czvdgy?file=/src/index.js)

This is pretty basic, and you can (and should) improve it.

### Edit

Ooops, I forgot that this was tagged as ReactJs. Here's the same example with React (codesandbox link is in the comments):

```
import React from "react";

const ORIGINAL_TEXT =
  "Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world.";

const splitText = (text, from, to) => [
  text.slice(0, from),
  text.slice(from, to),
  text.slice(to)
];

const HighlightedText = ({ text, from, to }) => {
  const [start, highlight, finish] = splitText(text, from, to);
  return (
    <p>
      {start}
      <span style={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>{highlight}</span>
      {finish}
    </p>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [highlightSection, setHighlightSection] = React.useState({
    from: 0,
    to: 0
  });
  const handleClick = () => {
    const synth = window.speechSynthesis;
    if (!synth) {
      console.error("no tts");
      return;
    }

    let utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(ORIGINAL_TEXT);
    utterance.addEventListener("boundary", (event) => {
      const { charIndex, charLength } = event;
      setHighlightSection({ from: charIndex, to: charIndex + charLength });
    });
    synth.speak(utterance);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HighlightedText text={ORIGINAL_TEXT} {...highlightSection} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>klik me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ooops sorry, I forgot this was tagged as 'reactjs'. Here's another codesandbox with the same stuff with react: https://codesandbox.io/s/tts-with-word-highlight-react-fz15tu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Awesome answer!!! For the vanilla JS version, it replaces the `innerHTML` of the entire container. Assuming the container has properly formatted HTML, this will change the entire markup. Is there a way to maintain the way the document is originally but still highlight the spoken texts?

Comment: Probably you want to keep your target text in some container (like a `<span>`) especially for text subject to highlighting, and perform the highlighting on that target. If that is not possible (say, you are writing a plugin or otherwise operating on unknown content) you could use a [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) to obtain all `textNode`s and filter out unwanted text, and then wrap these in such containers. Like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/highlight-textnodes-732jhb?file=/index.html

Comment: I got all the `textNodes`  using `getAllTextNodes`. Then I do, ```const markRange = (nodes: Array<Node>, charIndex: number, charLength: number) => {
 let i = 0;
 const range = document.createRange();
 range.collapse(true);
 try {
  range.setEnd(nodes[i], charIndex + charLength);
  range.setStart(nodes[i], charIndex);
 } catch (error) {
  i += 1;
  range.setEnd(nodes[i], charIndex + charLength);
  range.setStart(nodes[i], charIndex);
 }

 const mark = document.createElement('mark');
 range.surroundContents(mark);
};```. When I call it in boundary, I get "Uncaught DOMException..."

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I wanted to implement Text-To-Speech on the web. Then I do research:

[See my complete research about this](https://github.com/albirrkarim/react-speech-highlight-demo/)

### This is what I got:

#### Using [Web Speech Synthesis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis)

When we using built in browser web speech synthesis API its free but, it comes with various problem. like robot like sound, wrong spelling, etc.. [see all problems](https://github.com/albirrkarim/react-speech-highlight-demo/blob/main/PROBLEMS.md)

#### Using Audio File

We can achieve good human like voices by using audio file. But, when we want to perform TTS with audio file we need transcript timestamp like this:

```
[
  {
    text: "hello world",
    start: 0
    end: 1.2
  }
]
```

The transcript timestamp generation is theoretically require machine learning.

### Solution

Then i decide make [React / Vanilla Speech Highlight](https://github.com/albirrkarim/react-speech-highlight-demo)
npm package that can combines all the benefits from TTS with [Web Speech Synthesis API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis) and TTS using Audio File.

You can make the audio file using various speech synthesis API provider like [ElevenLabs](https://elevenlabs.io/?from=partnermurray4444), Google Cloud TTS, Amazon Polly, and Open AI.

How about transcript timestamp to perform TTS using an audio file?

I make transcript timestamp detection engine. So my package can read the audio and produce transcript timestamp.

Here the [demo website](https://react-speech-highlight.vercel.app) you can try the capability.

[See my complete research about this](https://github.com/albirrkarim/react-speech-highlight-demo/)

## Example Code

#### Styling the highlighter

File `App.css`

```css
.highlight-spoken {
  color: black !important;
  background-color: #ff6f00 !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.highlight-sentence {
  color: #000000 !important;
  background-color: #ffe082 !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

#### The code example

File `App.js`

```
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { markTheWords, useTextToSpeech } from "react-speech-highlight";

export default function App() {
  const text = "Some Input String";
  const textEl = useRef();
  const lang = "en-US";

  const { controlHL, statusHL, prepareHL, spokenHL } = useTextToSpeech({
    disableSentenceHL: false,
    disableWordHL: false,
    autoScroll: false,
    lang: lang,
  });

  const textHL = useMemo(() => markTheWords(text), [text]);

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={textEl}>
        <div
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: textHL,
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>

      <PanelControlTTS
        isPlay={statusHL == "play" || statusHL == "calibration"}
        play={() => {
          if (statusHL == "pause") {
            controlHL.resume();
          } else {
            controlHL.play(
              textEl.current
            );
          }
        }}
        pause={controlHL.pause}
        stop={controlHL.stop}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

#### Sample TTS Control

File `PanelControlTTS.js`

```
export default function PanelControlTTS({ isPlay, play, pause, stop }) {
  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          if (isPlay) {
            pause();
          } else {
            play();
          }
        }}
      >
        {isPlay ? "pause" : "play"}
      </button>

      {isPlay && <button onClick={stop}>stop</button>}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[tts-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tts-react) provides a hook `useTts` that accepts a `markTextAsSpoken` argument that will highlight the words being spoken.

Here's an example:

```js
import { useTts } from 'tts-react'

const TTS = ({ children }) => {
  const { ttsChildren, play } = useTts({ children, markTextAsSpoken: true })

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={play}>
        Click to hear the text spoken
      </button>
      {ttsChildren}
    </div>

  )
}

const App = () => {
  return <TTS>Some text to be spoken.</TTS>
}
```

You can load it from a CDN too:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>tts-react UMD example</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tts-react@1.2.0/dist/umd/tts-react.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
      const { TextToSpeech, useTts } = TTSReact
      const CustomTTS = ({ children }) => {
        const { play, ttsChildren } = useTts({ children, markTextAsSpoken: true })

        return (
          <>
            <button onClick={() => play()}>Play</button>
            <div>{ttsChildren}</div>
          </>
        )
      }

      root.render(
        <>
          <CustomTTS>
            <p>Highlight words as they are spoken.</p>
          </CustomTTS>
          <TextToSpeech markTextAsSpoken>
            <p>Highlight words as they are spoken.</p>
          </TextToSpeech>
        </>
      )
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```